# Execute the script using crontab

Tags: php, cron

I need to execute a php script once in a day.
I followed these steps to make the script run.
crontab -e

```
30 17 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/file.php  >> /var/log/1.log >2&1
```

Its not working.There is nothing inside 1.log(1.log is the file which i have created)

I checked the log file using

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

CMD redirected to /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/file.php  >> /var/log/1.log >2&1
MTA was not installed ,discarded the output.

but i do not want a mail to be sent so i do not want to install MTA. I just want cronjob to be run.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check your cron log to see if there's any information there. But `sudo` may be throwing it off. In most linux installations, sudo requires a password.

Comment: You can update to `30 17 * * * sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/file.php >> /var/log/what_happens.log` to see what the output is during execution. Also note `17:30` is `5:30 PM` according to your server's clock. May not be your `5:30 pm` your time

Comment: @user3783243 whether the file what_happen.log will be created automatically or i have to create before running the crontab.

Comment: @Jyothi It will create it, assuming you have a `/var/log` directory